# BinarySearchTree insert method

Tags: java, insert, binary-search-tree

I am trying to use recursive to write an insert method for BST.

```
 public void insert(DictEntry data) throws BSTException {
     if (find(data.getPosition()) == data){
         throw new BSTException();
     }
     else {
         if (current == null){
             root.setRoot(data);
     }
         else {
             while(current != null){
                 if (data.getPosition().compareTo(root.getRoot().getPosition()) < 0){
                     current = current.getLeft();
                 }
                 else{
                     if (data.getPosition().compareTo(root.getRoot().getPosition()) > 0){
                         current = current.getRight();
                     }
                     else
                         ;
                 }
                 insert(data);
             }
         }

     }
 }
```

But I don't know for some reason the test case always fail.
Could someone help me fix it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with this code:

1. You mixed up the recursive implementation with the iterative one. When using recursion as you do by calling "insert(data)" inside the function "insert" you do not need the "while" loop
2. When you finally hit the base case of your recursion `if (current == null){` you insert at the root? You should insert at "current", as this is the sub tree you found out to be empty and match the order
3. You always compare your data to "root" instead of "current"

Further issues:

- Your code is badly formatted ("}" after the first "else" should be indented more, "else ;" is unnecessary)
- You are using recursion by updating a variable outside of the function: "current". This may work, but it is bad style. Your method should look like `public void insert(DictEntry data, BSTNode node)` where you start with `insert(data, root)` and then recursively call `insert(data, node.getLeft()` or `insert(data, node.getRight()`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my problems. For this method, the constructor is fixed, which is "public void insert(DictEntry data) throws BSTException " (I wish I could have insert(DictEntry data, BSTNode node))...